# Title show while timer is enabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

so I have a problem where I want to make a label pop up when timer is enabled. I tried writing this but it just doesn't work. I have set every object property as needed, but still there is some kind of problem. Can you help me please? Thanks.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button3Click == true && FullNameBOX.Text == "")
        {
            timer1.Start();
             while(timer1.Enabled == true)
            {
                label5.Show();
            }
            
            timer1.Stop();

        }
        else if(timer1.Enabled == false)
        {
            label5.Hide();
        }
        else
        {

        }
```

Comment: When the Timer is not enabled, its `Tick` event is not raised. So, you're trying to start it when it's already started and you cannot verify if it's disable, because the code in the handler is never called. -- What causes the Timer to start and stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timer1_Tick` is only executed once the timer is started and the timer interval is elapsed for the first time and then repeatedly every interval. So you must start the timer somewhere else. In button `button3_Click` I assume

```cs
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FullNameBOX.Text == "")
    {
        label5.Show();
        timer1.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        ... process the FullNameBOX.Text
    }
}
```

In the Tick event handler stop the timer and hide the label

```cs
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    label5.Hide();
}
```

Also, give better names to your controls. It's best to do so before creating the event handlers so that those get better names too. It is easier to understand `messageLabel` than `label5` and `SaveButton_Click` than `button3_Click`.

Comment: Tak you so much. You dot even know how much you just helped me. God bless you 